# Ember one-way input does not update its value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an custom component that serves as an input (in my application it does more things, but I've wanted to keep same structure so I've wrapped native input into component).

Then when user changes value of an input, I am calling closure action to format value provided by user (in example I am uppercasing it) and set it to some property (which should be visible for user in input).

Problem happens when I paste some lowercased string (for example `abc`), and then without deleting nor adding anything I just select everything and paste from clipboard (again  `abc`). At second paste the formatting closure action is called, even setter of an property is called (I've tried computed property with custom `set`), but my component's input stays unformatted.

I've provided minimal Ember Twiddle to play with: https://ember-twiddle.com/5448bb455fd8732cc87f6ed8f2d44c12

Answer (score 0):

The value is updated in action handler of `application controller`. At that handler, `toUpperCase` is called and result is set to `a`.

In the second call, since the `a` is not changed, `value` of `my-input` will not changed. So the component will not re-render. And pasted value will stay remained.

You can watch this situation by adding `{{log (concat 'test' a)}}` line to the `application.hbs`. It will printed only one time.

To make it work: Put the making `uppercase` logic to the `my-input` component. It will simply work. Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/86a6bd8d7a7d0dd7af2893c2a3a0f0f8?openFiles=components.my-input.js%2C), you can implement similar component.

Comment: I understand why your proposed solution works, but I think that data mutation at later stage isn't anything unusual, and it should be possible to match it somehow

Comment: IMO, converting to uppercase is a responsibility of the input component. Is it ok?

Comment: There is a [simplistic solution](https://ember-twiddle.com/86a6bd8d7a7d0dd7af2893c2a3a0f0f8?openFiles=components.my-input.js%2C) of course. Can you check [it](https://ember-twiddle.com/86a6bd8d7a7d0dd7af2893c2a3a0f0f8?openFiles=components.my-input.js%2C)? But it causes flickering. To prevent flickering the only solution I know is handling the `keydown` or `keypress`...

Comment: It's not flickering for me. This is similar what I was trying to do. Thanks for input anyway. You can update your answer so I can mark it as solved, though I am not 100% sure it's best way

Comment: @MyFantasy512 Ok, I've updated my answer. I've removed the complex one.